How to simulate for the Gain of opamp Bridge Differential Amplifier?

Hi experts,
I have this circuit, with a bridge connected to an op-amp in differential form, and I want to simulate it for the Gain of the circuit in PSPICE.
I have found it's gain by hand, which comes to be around 200.
As there is no specific Ri resistor, I had to use Thevenin's Theorem to find the input Voltage at inverting(as input voltage at non-inverting can easily be found) and using superposition found the output voltage.
But if I want to simulate it, what input voltage should I use, because I can't just use
Vp-Vn, as that leads to gain of more than 4000, which I know is wrong.
Please help me, this is my first post.
PS:


Whatever way you look at this, $V_p=V_n$, within a few microvolts. It doesn't make any sense to talk of voltage gain in terms of $V_p$ or $V_n$. Perhaps it makes sense to talk of common-mode gain.

You can't use Vp-Vn ... because then you have the gain of the opamp (function also of frequency, perhaps 100k to 1 000 k ...).
You should search the "gain" (transfer function) versus the value of a resistor (r3 or r4 for example, some resistance sensor).


Thankyou very very much for helping me.
But I didn't get you completely. At around 90 ohms, as you have shown, the v(out) becomes, zero. But how does tell us the gain of circuit?

Don't speak of "gain". It is only "the" value of "vo" for a given "R4". When vo=0, it is a "well-balanced" bridge. We could speak of "gain" (transfer function, non-linear) when we take 2 values and calculate the "differential gain" (dVo/dR) which has here the dimension of a "current" (non-linear).

First, you calculate Vp using voltage division.  This is accurate because the input impedance of the noninverting op amp input is relatively high.
Next, because our "standard" op amp assumptions tell us Vn=Vp,, you take the expression for Vp, in terms of R1 and R3 into a Kirchoff's Current Law equation at the Vn node, and use that to derive an expression for Vout.
Now comes the hard part.  You then do algebraic manipulation to take your expression for Vout, and come up with an equation of the following form:
$$ V_{\text{out}}= (V_p-V_n)*f(\text{params})+ \frac{(V_p+V_n)}{2}*g(\text{params})$$
The function \$f\$ is knows as your differential gain, and the function \$g\$ is called the common mode gain.
This can be a difficult process.  It can be very hard to isolate these terms.  This is why I often put a voltage follower after Vp and Vn, and use a standard differential amp after the followers,  or instrumentation amp without using the followers  -- this make the equations dirt simple.

Thankyou verymuch
